# choose photo from gallery for s7, s7 edge, note 5 not working

Tags: android, image, image-gallery

I have an app where I am uploading the image from Gallery. This is working fine with Note 4, OS 6.0, however it is not working for Note 5, S7, S7 edge.

***What I mean by is not working is*** *I can see Gallery, however when I select image, gallery get dismissed only. Nothing ahead happened.*

Did this happened with anyone before?

***Right now I am not posting code because might someone know why this is happening. I will post my code incase if needed.***

***targetSdkVersion is 21, that means I don't to worry about permissions for now. The problem lies somewhere else.***

Comment: once face this kind of problem. Use this https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: What operating system are all these running ? 6.0 ?

Comment: @AbhinavArora : S7, S7 Edge, Note 5 use minimum 6.0

Comment: @JaydeepPatel : how that solve your problem?

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: it has some uri problems some time it is return whith prefix content:// or sometimes without sometimes file:// etc., there are many possibilities there. so it is better to use library and if you want to crop that image then it is even better.

Comment: @KrunalPatel : target sdk is 21

Comment: put your code hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this device is when you choose image from gallery the onActivityResult() call in normal case but when you choose image from this devices your onCreate() method will call and nothing will happens due to onCreate() so the solution is that write below properties in androidmanifest file of your activity.This works for me.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: Just write the android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
in your activity file declare in androidmainifest file it will call your onActivityResult

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586214/disable-other-option-then-gallery-for-s7-edge-other-new-devices)

Answer (score 0):

please put run time permission if targetSdkVersion above lollipop.

Comment: put log in onactivityResult and check.                                         @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(requestCode == 1){
   
   if(data != null){
    
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Log.v(TAG, "Uri=="+uri);
  }
  }
 }

Comment: intresting thing is I don't have  these phones, client have... so i can't check..

Comment: `Uri uri = data.getData();` is failing... `Uri==` its blank